# Can't find the package when packaging a Magento Extension

Tags: magento

I have created a new theme for magento.I want to submit it to the communtity.When i tried to package extension,I m getting **The package data has been saved** message,but there is no package in var/pear directory.Is it not possible to pack extension in localhost?Do you need more information?Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see this article:- [Magento: How to create extension package? (IMAGES)](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-create-extension-package-images/)

Check if the data is filled correctly.

While creating your extension package, under **Package Info -> Supported releases**

- If you have chosen "**1.5.0.0 & later**" then your extension package is stored in **var/connect** directory. This supports Magento connect 2.0.
- If you have chosen "**Pre-1.5.0.0**" then your extension package is stored in **var/pear** directory. This is for Magento connect 1.0.
- If you have selected both options, then the extension packages is stored in both places (var/connect and var/pear).

> When uploading the 1.0 version from var/pear – Magento Connect will
>   make the 2.0 version for you. If you wish to only support 1.5 and
>   higher versions of Magento only then only upload the 2.0 file from the
>   var/connect directory to Magento. Source:
>   http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/7_-_magento_connect/packaging_a_magento_extension_in_1.5

**Edit**:

I tried to create a package with **app/design** and **skin** folder. It worked fine and I could see other folder and files in the package file inside **var/pear**.

I tested with default theme and default skin. In '**Contents**' section, I kept like this:-

```
Target: Magento Theme Skin
Path: frontend/default/default
Type: Recursive Dir

Target: Magento User Interface
Path: frontend/default/default
Type: Recursive Dir
```

Comment: @chapagain:Thanks for your help.I will package an extension in the way that you sent.

Comment: When packaging a theme as extension do we have create a config.xml file?

Comment: @chapagain: I am creating theme as package.I get the the message that "The package data has been saved" and tgz file,package.xml file created in connect folder.But when i extract the file,it has no data.I wonder what went wrong!

Answer (score 0):

What version did you select for "Supported releases"? Check in the `var/package/` folder too. Check both folders have user and group write access.

Comment: Magento 1.5 version.I selected 1.5.0.0 & later.var/package/ folder has write permission.No luck!

Answer (score 0):

Packges are saved with a `.tgz` extension, so running

```
find . -name '*.tgz'
```

from the magento base folder is always a good way to find your packages.

Also, as of 1.5, Magento changed their package management system.  This is why you had to choose a supported releases option.  For 1.5 and later packages Magento will, by default, drop the files into

```
var/connect
```

The `var/package` folder is only used if you opt to create a pre 1.5 package.