# How to package magento extension

Tags: magento

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Magento Packaging an Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910262/magento-packaging-an-extension)

Hi,

I have created a wireframe theme for magento(1.5).I m trying to pack as an extension.But its not working.Here's what i did.I put my theme file wireframe(app,skin)in **./app/code/local/**.
I selected magento local module has target path,I gave ./app/code/local/ in path.Is this correct?.What should i give in type section.What is the difference between **file and recursive dir**.
Magento creating 1kb zip file in var/connect/.But when i extract,i can see only xml file.
Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I selected magento local module has
>   target path,I gave ./app/code/local/
>   in path.Is this correct?

No. This is not correct.

**Magento Local Module** file is relative to **app/code/local/**. So, here you should give path as **YourNamespace/YourModule** and select Type as **Recursive Dir**.

> What is the difference between file
>   and recursive dir?

**File** means single file. Like a module global file in **app/etc/YourNamespace_YourModule.xml**.

**Recursive Dir** means a whole directory. Like in **app/code/local/YourNamespace/YourModule**.

After you create package, the package module is inside **var/pear** directory.

Hope this helps.

**Edit**:-

For skin files, select contents as below:-

**Target** = Magento Theme Skin (Images, CSS, JS) [ This is relative to **skin/** (a slash after skin)]

**Path** = frontend/default/default/css/styles.css

See this article for screenshots:- [Magento: How to create extension package? (IMAGES)](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-create-extension-package-images/)

Comment: Is it necessary to have namespace for a theme file?How to pack app,skin files as extension?

Comment: answer edited. For skin files, you need to select Target as "Magento Theme Skin (Images, CSS, JS)"